# RXJava logical map chain

Tags: java, rx-java

I have following code written in RXJava.

```
validateProduct(payload)
.map.(r -> {
    if(r.getBoolean("valid")){
        return createProduct(productPayload);
    }else{
        return null; // request.end() | end the chain here with some message as invalid product.
    }
})
.map(r -> {
    return linkCategories(catPayload);
})
.map(r -> {
    return linkTags(tagPayload);
})
.doOnError(e -> log.error(e))
.subscribe(r -> {
    JsonObject response = new JsonObject().put("status", true);
    request.end(response);
}, e -> {
    JsonObject response = new JsonObject().put("status", false);
    request.end(response);
});
```

The first block has a condition check, this code is not working right now. Whats the best way to handle conditional chains in RX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are probably running into a null pointer exception. nulls are not acceptable in RxJava v2. Your first map is likely causing problems.

Generally when you need conditional logic in rxjava and may not be returning an object you have two options:

1. Return an object that signifies null (and possibly filter it out)
2. Use an operator like flatMap and add on an empty Observable

It looks like you are probably running into a null pointer exception.  nulls are not acceptable in RxJavav2.  Your first map is likely causing problems.

Option 1.

```
validateProduct(payload)
.map.(r -> {
    if(r.getBoolean("valid")){
        return createProduct(productPayload);
    }else{
        return createEmptyProduct(); // generate non null placeholder object
    }
})
.filter(r->{
    // check here via method call or instanceOf to filter out empty products
    r instanceof ValidProduct
}).map(r -> {
    return linkCategories(catPayload);
})
.map(r -> {
    return linkTags(tagPayload);
})
.doOnError(e -> log.error(e))
.subscribe(r -> {
    JsonObject response = new JsonObject().put("status", true);
    request.end(response);
}, e -> {
    JsonObject response = new JsonObject().put("status", false);
    request.end(response);
});
```

Option 2

```
validateProduct(payload)
.flatMap(r -> {
    if(r.getBoolean("valid")){
        return createProduct(productPayload); // Assuming this returns an observable if not use Observable.just(createProduct(productPayload))
    }else{
        return Observable.empty(); // request.end() | end the chain here with some message as invalid product.
    }
})
.map(r -> {
    return linkCategories(catPayload);
})
.map(r -> {
    return linkTags(tagPayload);
})
.doOnError(e -> log.error(e))
.subscribe(r -> {
    JsonObject response = new JsonObject().put("status", true);
    request.end(response);
}, e -> {
    JsonObject response = new JsonObject().put("status", false);
    request.end(response);
});
```

Comment: in the second option, where you are returning `return Observable.empty();`, will `linkCategories(catPayload)` be called?

Comment: @MinatoNamikaze nope